# How to make vimrc changes to take effect

Tags: linux, vim

I have a problem using my `.vimrc`. I am under Linux Red hat and whatever I change in `~/.vimrc` does not take effect. To make it reflected, each time I open vim files (let say `hello.txt`), I need to source `so:~/.vimrc` to make my new changes reflected.
But I don't want to do sourcing every time. I wonder if there would be a way to source it once and have all new configurations valid.

I also should note that I do not have root access and I had to create my own `.vimrc` for the first time. It did not exist in my `$HOME` directory.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

```
>which vim
/usr/bin/vim
>ls -la ~/.vimrc
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 username ...
```

my system wide Vim initialization:

`/usr/share/vim/vimrc`

my personal Vim initializations

`~/.vimrc`

**UPDATE 2**:

`:scriptnames:`

```
1: /etc/vimrc
 2: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/syntax.vim
 3: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/synload.vim
 4: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/syncolor.vim
 5: /usr/share/vim/vim72/filetype.vim
 6: /usr/share/vim/vim72/ftplugin.vim
 7: /usr/share/vim/vim72/indent.vim
 8: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/nosyntax.vim
 9: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/filetype.vim
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 11: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/gzip.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/matchparen.vim
 13: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 14: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 15: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/spellfile.vim
 16: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 17: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/tohtml.vim
 18: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 19: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
```

Comment: Can you plase issue `which vim` and `ls -la ~/.vimrc`? Add the outputs and the version from the welcome screen when running `vim` without a file. Take a look at the `FILES` section in `man vim` if it states another location for a `.vimrc`.

Comment: @try-catch-finally I add an update to the question. I still don't know how to resolve it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I found the solution.

The reason that I was not able to make any changes get reflected from `~/.vimrc` was because of `VIMINIT`.
I had `VIMINIT` set in my shell configuration (`.cshrc`). And according to the vim documentation, `VIMINIT` has load precedence over `.vimrc`.

Comment: I encounter this problem too! Could you tell me how to solve it? `VIMINIT` was set to `set number`

Answer (score 2):

So, your general configuration in `~/.vimrc` works, but you don't see new changes applied immediately?

That's because Vim only reads the `~/.vimrc` once during startup. So in general, you have to `:quit` Vim and restart it. You can define autocmds that automatically reload your `~/.vimrc` on writes, see [Change vimrc with auto reload](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_vimrc_with_auto_reload). Some options are buffer-local and are only derived from the global defaults. For those, even such reload won't affect them.

Comment: I tried to quit vim and also added the `autocmd BufWritePost .vimrc source % ` in my vimrc. But it did not work. every time I need to source my `.vimrc`

Comment: To clarify, is that only for configuration added by an edit, or in general, the whole personal config? For the latter, check with `:scriptnames` and `:echo $MYVIMRC` what Vim reads and where it expects it.

Comment: apparently personal vimrc is not set properly. I can not see it after pulling `:scriptnames`. Please refer to the update2

Comment: Weird. Anything special with your `$HOME`? Does this work for another user on your system?

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for me;
Inside your vim write the following command

```
:source ~/.vimrc
```

This starts feeding commands from the .vimrc file

The .vimrc file is a file that collects all that .vim(...) files and combines all of them.

When you search .vim... you will get many other files starting with .vim
These files are the ones that feed the .vimrc file

Answer (score 1):

Here are two mappings I have in my vimrc to quickly open and refresh my vimrc file. After you add these make sure to open a new window so they can go into effect though :)

```
"refreshes for any vimrc updates
map <C-r> :source ~/.vimrc<CR>

"opens vimrc
map <C-o> :e ~/.vimrc<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ vim
```

then after it's started, type

```
:help initialization
```

That will explain what files are sourced on startup and in what order, then you can figure it out from there.

And it's normal for .vimrc and a .vim directory to not exist for a new user account.

Comment: I have the issue that the .vimrc file does not show in the starting list of files. How do I source them there?